# If ack finds results do this; else do that

Tags: bash, ack

I'm trying to write out a script that will automate one of my more tedious tasks. I've pretty much got everything down and can get the individual components of code to do what I want them to, but I'm running into trouble trying to get the if statement to work. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
if [ ack --ignore-case 'foo' ]; then
    Do this action
else
    Do that action
fi
```

As of now it always does the else action, even if the ack parameter is true.

Thanks!

Comment: `[` is a command, not `bash` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `[` - you want to check the exit status of ack:

```
if ack --ignore-case 'foo'; then
```

ack returns a 0 (success) exit status if a match is encountered.

Although it may look like a syntactical construct, `[` is in fact a function (synonymous with `test`), which returns 0 if the test passes. `if` is looking at the return code of this function. In this case, ack gives you the return code that you need instead, so you shouldn't also be using `[`.

Comment: D'oh! It's always the little things. I'll give this a check in 6 minutes when the site will allow me to

Comment: @eBooks_Nashville if your do this, do that are short commands you may be interested also in the alternative syntax `ack ... && do_this || do_that`

Answer (score 3):

Just drop the square brackets

```
if ack --ignore-case 'foo' ; then
    Do this action
else
    Do that action
fi
```

You don't want to check that the string `ack --ignore-case 'foo'` is non-empty, you want to check ack's exit status.

You should have recieved a warning telling you so:

```
-bash: [: --ignore-spaces: binary operator expected
```